# try cach swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode

Buenas tengo un problema en parte de mi aplicación. Lo que hace es buscar la posición del celular y pasar la latitud y longitud por medio de un enlace.
Ahora bien para que esto funcione obviamente en el celular tiene que estar activado el modo GPS y por lo cual me gustaria controlar ese error con un try cach.
Me he fijado en ejemplos pero sinceramente no he logrado adaptarlo. Les comparto mi codigo y el error lo tira en la parte de

**latitud = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude**

**longitud = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude** .

```
var locationManager : CLLocationManager?
var latitud = 0.0
var longitud = 0.0
var currentLocation: CLLocation!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        locationManager = appDelegate.locationManager
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        currentLocation = locationManager?.location

        print("esto trae latitud")

        latitud = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
        longitud = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude



        print("ESTO TRAE LATITUD  ->",latitud)
        print("ESTO TRAE LONGITUD  ->",longitud)
        let urlNombre = "http://www.exacto.com/usuario/index.php?v=1&lat=\(latitud)&Lng=\(longitud)"
        //TRAIGO LA PAGINA WEB Y LA INSERTO EN EL WEBVIEW
        print("Esto trae URLNombre"+urlNombre)
        if let url = URL(string: urlNombre){
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            self.webview.loadRequest(request)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mira si [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44070087/5587982) puede ser de tu ayuda, o bien [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24696878/5587982) con mucha mayor aceptación.

Comment: Gracias amigo, la verdad que estoy viendo que me viene null pero no entiendo por qué, quise hacer los ejemplos que me pasaste y me sigue fallando

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que se produzcan dos fallos:

1. En primer lugar como comentas que el usuario no tenga la localización, que lo compruebas de esta manera: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34862296/8818448 .
   Para poder usarlo debe estar en alguno de estos estados:.authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse
2. En segundo lugar es posible que no tengas permiso para acceder a la localización del usuario. Para pedir permiso al usuario debes hacer lo siguiente:
   Te adjunto un link que te puede servir de ayuda (https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/22/2/requesting-location-core-location)

---

```
import CoreLocation 
locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

implementas el delegado CLLocationManagerDelegate
y en esta función ya puedes utilizarlo

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .authorizedAlways {
        if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self) {
            if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable() {
                // aquí ya tienes acceso para utilizarlo
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.